# Change tableView when changing CoreData attribute criteria

Tags: uitableview, core-data, uibarbuttonitem

Looking for experienced advise since I'm newbie to iOS.
I have CoreData entities for "income" and "expenses". I've a tableView to show expenses and another one to show the income. I would like to group the expenses or income by month and display the data (expenses or income) on the tableView, and change the month displayed using toolbar buttons. To show by month seems simple, using an attribute "month" on entities. My question is what's the cleanest way to implement the "monthly display" and adapt the tableView to respond the "next month" and "previous month" buttons? 
For instance, I have the tableView showing the February Expenses. When I touch the next button I want to show a tableView with March Expenses.
What kind of approach do you suggest using "months"? This may be quite simple, but for someone who's starting can be quit tough if i take wrong directions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would use would be to have a typedef enum for the month (just for convenience)

```
typedef enum 
{
    January = 0,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
} Month;
```

Then you would have each entity have an attribute on it which is a number that indicates the month that entity is associated with.
You can then get all the entities associated with a specified month like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"<<Your entity name here>>" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSPredicate *monthPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"month.integerValue == %d", (NSInteger)month];
[request setPredicate:monthPredicate];
```

that request should get you all the entities associated with the given month.  If you want, you could also just save the month as a string.  Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply. It will take me some days to start implementing it, but you gave me a starting point. And how would you do to show the different tableViews (expenses and income) sync on the same month? This is, I have a TabBar where I can change from Expenses and Income. If my Expenses view is set to a specific month, i would like, when selecting Income, to show that same month that was selected for Expenses? Thanks for taking some time helping.

Comment: your suggestion was ok for what I asked. I ended up using two entities and a relationship with to many relationship. It fits better for what I had in mind. thanks for making me think and learn.